Most efficient way to access the off-diagonal entries of a matrix in Julia
Suppose I have a 200 x 200 zero matrix in Julia. What is the most efficient way to set the off-diagonal elements of the matrix using the elements of another matrix?
I have written this code:
function (A::Matrix{Complex64}, B::Matrix{Complex64})
  M = zeros(ComplexF64, 200, 200)
  OffDiags  = [i ≠ j for i ∈ 1:nbands, j ∈ 1:nbands]
  M[OffDiags] .= A[OffDiags] ./ B[OffDiags]
end

Is there is a more efficient way to do this?

Yes.  Below are an interpretation of the original algorithm and 4 faster algorithms.  Which is best may depend on the matrix size (and processor).
Original algorithm
As I understand, OffDiags is a Matrix{Boolean} used as an index.  Here is a runnable version.
using BenchmarkTools: @benchmark

function computeMatBool(M::Matrix{T}, A::Matrix{T}, B::Matrix{T}, nbands::N) where {T<:Number, N<:Integer}
  local nrows = first(size(M))
  local OffDiags = [i ≠ j && abs(i-j) <= nbands for i ∈ 1:nrows, j ∈ 1:nrows]
  M[OffDiags] .= A[OffDiags] ./ B[OffDiags]
  return M
end

function testComputeMatBool(; nrows=5, nbands=1)
    # random dense matrices
    A = rand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)
    B = rand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)

    M = zeros(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)

    @benchmark computeMatBool($M, $A, $B, $nbands)
end

testComputeMatBool(; nrows=200, nbands=2)

Calculating OffDiags costs O(nrows * ncols).  To avoid that, the versions below use a for-loop to iterate through a range of bands indices, or iterate through generated cell indices within the bands, without creating an intermediate collection.  They also try the same using BandedMatrix for compact memory access patterns.
Use band(bandIndex), on (dense) matrices
band(bandIndex) can be used to refer to the indices of the elements in a diagonal band.
bandIndex is 0 for the diagonal, 1 for the first band above the diagonal, -1 for the first band below the diagonal, etc.
using BandedMatrices: band
using BenchmarkTools: @benchmark

function computeForBandsOnDense(M::Matrix{T}, A::Matrix{T}, B::Matrix{T}, nbands::N) where {T<:Number, N<:Integer}
  for bandIndex in -nbands:nbands
      if bandIndex != 0
          M[band(bandIndex)] .= A[band(bandIndex)] ./ B[band(bandIndex)]
      end
  end
  return M
end

function testComputeForBandsOnDense(; nrows=5, nbands=1)
    # random dense matrices
    A = rand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)
    B = rand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)

    M = zeros(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)

    @benchmark computeForBandsOnDense($M, $A, $B, $nbands)
end

testComputeForBandsOnDense(; nrows=200, nbands=2)

Use band(bandIndex), on BandedMatrices
If the elements outside the bands are all zero, then BandedMatrices can save memory and keep the elements closer together in memory caches.
using BandedMatrices: BandedMatrix, bandrange, band, brand
using BenchmarkTools: @benchmark

function computeForBandsOnBanded(M::BandedMatrix{T}, A::BandedMatrix{T}, B::BandedMatrix{T}) where {T<:Number}
    for bandIndex in bandrange(M)
        if bandIndex != 0
            M[band(bandIndex)] .= A[band(bandIndex)] ./ B[band(bandIndex)]
        end
    end
    return M
end

function testComputeForBandsOnBanded(; nrows=5, nbands=1)
    # random example banded matices
    A = brand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows, nbands, nbands)
    B = brand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows, nbands, nbands)

    M = BandedMatrix(zeros(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows), (nbands, nbands))

    @benchmark computeForBandsOnBanded($M, $A, $B)
end

testComputeForBandsOnBanded(; nrows=200, nbands=2)

Generate indices only within bands, on dense matrices
As M is already zeroed, generating only the indices of band cells can be faster.
using BenchmarkTools: @benchmark

function computeForPairsOnDense(M::Matrix{T}, A::Matrix{T}, B::Matrix{T}, nbands::N) where {T<:Number, N<:Integer}
    local (nrows, ncols) = size(M)
    for OffDiagsPair in ((i, i+j) for i ∈ 1:nrows, j ∈ -nbands:nbands if j ≠ 0 && 1 ≤ i+j ≤ ncols)
        M[OffDiagsPair...] = A[OffDiagsPair...] / B[OffDiagsPair...]
    end
    return M
end

function testComputeForPairsOnDense(; nrows=5, nbands=1)
    # random dense matrices
    A = rand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)
    B = rand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)

    M = zeros(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows)

    @benchmark computeForPairsOnDense($M, $A, $B, $nbands)
end

testComputeForPairsOnDense(; nrows=200, nbands=2)

Generate indices only within bands, on BandedMatrices
using BandedMatrices: BandedMatrix, brand, bandwidths
using BenchmarkTools: @benchmark

function computeForPairsOnBanded(M::BandedMatrix{T}, A::BandedMatrix{T}, B::BandedMatrix{T}) where {T<:Number, N<:Integer}
  local (lbands, ubands) = bandwidths(M)
  local (nrows, ncols) = size(M)
  for OffDiagsPair in ((i, i+j) for i ∈ 1:nrows, j ∈ -lbands:ubands if j ≠ 0 && 1 ≤ i+j ≤ ncols)
    M[OffDiagsPair...] = A[OffDiagsPair...] / B[OffDiagsPair...]
  end
  return M
end

function testComputeForPairsOnBanded(; nrows=5, nbands=1)
    # random dense matrices
    A = brand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows, nbands, nbands)
    B = brand(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows, nbands, nbands)

    M = BandedMatrix(zeros(ComplexF64, nrows, nrows), (nbands, nbands))

    @benchmark computeForPairsOnBanded($M, $A, $B)
end

testComputeForPairsOnBanded(; nrows=200, nbands=2)

Results on older laptop, Julia 1.10.4
Result ordering may change depending on matrix size.
(Result ordering may depend on CPU cache size, CPU cache prefetch heuristics, etc.)
For nrows=200, nbands=2 (both upper and lower)



Relative avg time
Alloc count
Alloc KiB
Version




100%
7
70.75
MatBool


12%
32
26.94
ForBandsOnDense


11%
8
26.00
ForBandsOnBanded


10%
3
0.14
ForPairsOnBanded


9%
0
0.00
ForPairsOnDense



For nrows=800, nbands=4 (both upper and lower)



Relative avg time
Alloc count
Alloc KiB
Version




100%
10
874.58
MatBool


13%
64
203.62
ForBandsOnDense


11%
0
0
ForPairsOnDense


7%
16
201.75
ForBandsOnBanded


7%
3
0.14
ForPairsOnBanded




You can get a slight optimization using explicit loop and CartesianIndices (but not as much with C style nested loops and full i, j indexing):
using BenchmarkTools

const nbands = 200
a = rand(ComplexF64, nbands, nbands)
b = rand(ComplexF64, nbands, nbands)

function f1(A::Matrix{ComplexF64}, B::Matrix{ComplexF64})
    M = zeros(ComplexF64, nbands, nbands)
    OffDiags  = [i ≠ j for i ∈ 1:nbands, j ∈ 1:nbands]
    M[OffDiags] .= A[OffDiags] ./ B[OffDiags]
    return M
end

function f2(A::Matrix{ComplexF64}, B::Matrix{ComplexF64})
    M = zeros(ComplexF64, nbands, nbands)
    for c in CartesianIndices(M)
        c[1] == c[2] && continue
        M[c] = A[c] / B[c]
    end
    return M
end

function f3(A::Matrix{ComplexF64}, B::Matrix{ComplexF64})
    M = zeros(ComplexF64, nbands, nbands)
    for i in 1:nbands
        for j in 1:nbands
            i == j && continue
            M[i, j] = A[i, j] / B[i, j]
        end
    end
    return M
end


@btime f1(a, b)
@btime f2(a, b)
@btime f3(a, b)

yields
455.400 μs (12 allocations: 2.17 MiB)
323.000 μs (2 allocations: 625.05 KiB)
351.500 μs (2 allocations: 625.05 KiB)

